# Elasticsearch 6.0.1 NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_6_0_0

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-6

I am using elasticsearch 6.0.1 and on BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();
I am getting the below error. I have checked online, mostly people said that this happens if I have different versions of lucene jars in the classpath.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_6_0_0

at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:44)
at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.DeprecationLogger.<clinit>(DeprecationLogger.java:159)
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest.<clinit>(BulkRequest.java:67)
at com.gci.geospatial_analysis.db.es.EsIndexClient.insert_layer_metadata_bulk(EsIndexClient.java:19)
at com.gci.geospatial_analysis.ElasticsearchTest.insert_documents_test1(ElasticsearchTest.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Below is my pom and I don't think that I have any other lucene version in classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
  <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.l3s.boilerpipe/boilerpipe -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.l3s.boilerpipe</groupId>
  <artifactId>boilerpipe</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-ui-model -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>deeplearning4j-ui-model</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>deeplearning4j-nlp</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sql2o/sql2o -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.sql2o</groupId>
  <artifactId>sql2o</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This problem can be solved by looking at the elasticsearch dependency and introducing the corresponding jar package.
to see : 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by adding lucene-core as dependency.

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
  <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by excluding the lucene dependency in that particular jar, as my project was using couple other versions of lucene via elasticsearch :

```
<dependency>  <!-- This uses Lucene Core 5.4.1 -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> <!-- This uses Lucene Core 7.3.1, hence excluding & keeping older version.-->
        <groupId>com.intuit.fuzzymatcher</groupId>
        <artifactId>fuzzy-matcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

In your case decide which version you want to keep and in the exclude all the rest. It would take a couple of tries but works for sure.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers previously shown on this page worked for me.  The issue for me was that my index name had a capital letter in it.  Of course, by the time the error bubbled up into the Elastic Search client, it was this generic no field exception rather than something more informative.

BAD INDEX NAME: "index_A"

GOOD INDEX NAME: "index_a"