# What dependencies do I add for elasticsearch's SearchRequest?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, pom.xml

This is how I'm constructing it:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
```

IntelliJ added all imports, and I've added dependencies in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My elastic search version also matches the client:

```
{
  "name" : "hQanR4j",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "50rqwF7hTbCPsBWgzEydpw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.4.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "595516e",
    "build_date" : "2018-08-17T23:18:47.308994Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I see this error when I put breakpoint on the line which creates the SearchRequest object: "Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest"

If I don't have breakpoint I get this error: "LUCENE_6_0_0"

I tried to enclose it in a try..catch to print Exception information but it is not getting caught. I think I haven't added right dependencies for SearchRequest.

It is not a duplicate of [Elastic Search Lucene version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309354/elastic-search-lucene-version-error)

I've purged elasticsearch and then removed /var/lib/elasticsearch/ directory and then installed it again and the problem still persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elastic Search Lucene version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309354/elastic-search-lucene-version-error)

Comment: I tried apt-get purge and then install of elasticsearch and the issue still persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch 6.0.1 NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE\_6\_0\_0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313461/elasticsearch-6-0-1-nosuchfielderror-lucene-6-0-0)